# Installing Tensorflow for Python 2.7 for Keras and CoreML conversion on Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, windows-10, keras, coreml

I am currently working on an artificial neural network model with Keras for image recognition and I want to convert it using CoreML.

Unfortunately, I have been working with Python3 and CoreML only works with Python 2.7 at the moment. Moreover, Tensorflow for Python 2.7 does not seem to be supported by Windows... So my only hope is to find a way to install it.

I saw some tips using Docker Toolbox but I did not catch it and I failed when trying this solution, even though it looks like the only thing that works.

So, is there any quite simple way to install Tensorflow for Python 2.7 on Windows 10?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Another solution could be to find/create a custom converter from Keras to Xcode (.h5 to .mlmodel format). I am collecting information on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-optimal solution (the only one I found) in my opinion, is to install a Linux virtual machine. I used VitualBox for it.

Then, it is very easy to download Anaconda and Python 2, as well as the right versions of the packages. For example, you can download Tensorflow 1.1.0 using the following command `$ pip install -I tensorflow==1.1.0`.